# Difference between 2 and 2. in tf.constant() - Dynamic Assignment of Datatypes in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

What is the difference between,

```
tf.constant([[1,2.]], shape=(1,2))
```

and

```
tf.constant([[1,2]], shape=(1,2))
```

Specifically, what does the dot mean?

Comment: 2. is the same as 2.0 a float. 2 is an integer.

Comment: On top of what @skullgoblet1089 said, also read about `dtype` associated with tf.constant [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/constant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such cases, it is always suggested that you check the data types explicitly using, say, the following example:

g = tf.constant([[1, 2.0]])

print(g.dtype) # output is <dtype: 'float32'>